# TypeError saying that object doesn't take parameters

Tags: function, class, object, parameters, attributes

```
class Car:
    def _init_(self,ma="",mo="",yr=0,p=0):
         self.make=ma
         self.model=mo
         self.year=yr
         self.price=p
    def _str_(self):
         res=""
         res += self.make
         res += " "
         res += self.model
         res += " "
         res += str(self.year)
         res += " "
         res += str(self.price)
         return res
    def applyDiscount(self,rate):
         newPrice=self.price-self.price*rate
         self.price=newPrice
         return self.price

 myCar=Car("Dodge","Caravan", 2021,3000)
 print(myCar.applyDiscount(.12))

 other=Car("subaru","Legacy",2007,300)
 print(myCar)
 print(other)
```

Why do I keep getting this error?
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 38, in 
TypeError: Car() takes no arguments

I tried creating a class but when I attempt to create an object it says that I can't have attributes for that object.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that you need to add here is one character '_' in the *init* function which should originally be **init**

So the right code would be:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self,ma="",mo="",yr=0,p=0):
        self.make=ma
        self.model=mo
        self.year=yr
        self.price=p
    def __str__(self):
        res=""
        res += self.make
        res += " "
        res += self.model
        res += " "
        res += str(self.year)
        res += " "
        res += str(self.price)
        return res
    def applyDiscount(self,rate):
        newPrice=self.price-self.price*rate
        self.price=newPrice
        return self.price

myCar = Car("Dodge","Caravan", 2021,3000)
print(myCar.applyDiscount(.12))

other = Car("subaru","Legacy",2007,300)
print(myCar)
print(other)
```